# Build Chromium with error about libgio on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: build, chromium

I tried to build Chromium on my Ubuntu 10.04 with the cmd, ninja -v -C out/Debug chrome. 
But I got this error, and found nothing by googling related information.

I've followed the instructions on http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxBuildInstructions before building. 
Could someone help me if you know how to resovle this? Thanks a lot.

```
In file included from obj/build/linux/gio.gen/libgio_loader.cc:4:
../../out/Debug/gen/library_loaders/libgio.h:28: error: ‘::g_settings_new’ has not been declared
../../out/Debug/gen/library_loaders/libgio.h:29: error: ‘::g_settings_get_child’ has not been declared
../../out/Debug/gen/library_loaders/libgio.h:30: error: ‘::g_settings_get_string’ has not been declared
../../out/Debug/gen/library_loaders/libgio.h:31: error: ‘::g_settings_get_boolean’ has not been declared
../../out/Debug/gen/library_loaders/libgio.h:32: error: ‘::g_settings_get_int’ has not been declared
../../out/Debug/gen/library_loaders/libgio.h:33: error: ‘::g_settings_get_strv’ has not been declared
../../out/Debug/gen/library_loaders/libgio.h:34: error: ‘::g_settings_list_schemas’ has not been declared
obj/build/linux/gio.gen/libgio_loader.cc: In member function ‘bool LibGioLoader::Load(const std::string&)’:
obj/build/linux/gio.gen/libgio_loader.cc:42: error: cast from ‘void*’ to ‘int’ loses precision
obj/build/linux/gio.gen/libgio_loader.cc:56: error: cast from ‘void*’ to ‘int’ loses precision
obj/build/linux/gio.gen/libgio_loader.cc:70: error: cast from ‘void*’ to ‘int’ loses precision
obj/build/linux/gio.gen/libgio_loader.cc:84: error: cast from ‘void*’ to ‘int’ loses precision
obj/build/linux/gio.gen/libgio_loader.cc:98: error: cast from ‘void*’ to ‘int’ loses precision
obj/build/linux/gio.gen/libgio_loader.cc:112: error: cast from ‘void*’ to ‘int’ loses precision
obj/build/linux/gio.gen/libgio_loader.cc:126: error: cast from ‘void*’ to ‘int’ loses precision
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codereview.chromium.org/21687002

Remove bundled gsettings header now that we're using Ubuntu Precise. you can build with 12.04

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. Digging up a little bit more, I found that the latest releases of GTK doesn't have above APIs. Please follow the below steps to build Chromium on Ubuntu 10.04:

1. Download an old release of GTK, for ex. from http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/glib/2.38/glib-2.38.2.tar.xz
2. Extract, configure, compile and install this.
3. Re-generate your chromium projects
4. Build again using ninja -C out/Debug chrome